# How to log events every 20 occurs using log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a loop.  I would like to see some log every 20 (100) execution.  So far I have some fairly elaborate code to do that,

```
for( int i = 0; i < aValues.length; ++i )
{
    if( c_LOG.isTraceEnabled() && ( ( i % 20 ) == 0 ) )
    {
        c_LOG.trace( "Converted item (" + i + ") " );
    }
    .....
}
```

This code does what I want, but the code is long (4 lines) and codes like that appear many times.  I cannot pack it into a method because that will screw the method name in the log output.  (`log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{3}:(%M %L) %m%n`) Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to just refactor:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < aValues.length; ++i) {
        if (shouldLog(i)) {
            c_LOG.trace("Converted item (" + i + ")");
        }
        ....
    } 

    ....

public boolean shouldLog(int n) {
    return shouldLog(n, 20);
}

public boolean shouldLog(int n, int mod) {
    return c_LOG.isTraceEnabled() && ((n % mod) == 0);
}
```

Comment: see. That is basically extract the condition testing as a new method.  Not bad for now.  thanks.